# Simple counters not working in C

Tags: c, loops, counter

I am new to C have come across a problem that I think some of you may have had in the past. I am trying to code a program that has the user input a bunch of grades and the program tells you how many A,B,C,D,Fs you have entered.
How ever, the problem is that my counter for the grades just wont work.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdint.h>

//MACRO
#define F_Range (0-49)
#define D_Range (50-59)
#define C_Range (60-69)
#define B_Range (70-79)
#define A_Range (80-100)
#define A_COUNTer
#define B_COUNTer
#define C_COUNter
#define D_COUNTer
#define F_COUNTer
//Function Prototype
void display(void);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    {

        float input, F_Counter, D_Counter, C_Counter, B_Counter, A_Counter;
        printf("Total Number of grades 'A' (80-100) = %.2f",A_Counter);
        //the rest of the displays would go here
        do
        {
            fflush (stdin);
            scanf("%f",&input); //Get input from user
            if (input == F_Range);
            {
                F_Counter++;
            }
            if (input == D_Range);
            {
                D_Counter++;
            }
            if (input == C_Range);
            {
                C_Counter++;
            }
            if (input == B_Range);
            {
                B_Counter++;
            }
            if (input == A_Range);
            {
                A_Counter++;
            }

        }

        while (input != 999);
        //Exit
        {

        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: please add the relevant code here itself. People on restricted access might not have access to other sites.

Comment: for start you have two "{" at the start of the main and two "}", while this isn't an error, this is just not needed

Comment: Okay, I will post codes here from now on.
And Thanks No Idea, I have noted that.

Comment: `input == F_Range`, how does that work on c?

Answer (score 1):

ok so for start when using `#define x y` you simply say "change all the reference to 'x' with 'y'" so when you have

```
#define C_Range (60-69)
```

and then

```
 if (input == C_Range );
```

it iterputes as

```
 if (input == (60-69));
```

which makes no sense, plus **you have the ";" at the end of the `if` statement** which doesn't make sense either

instead use:

```
#define F_RangeLow 0
#define F_RangeHigh 49
```

and the if statement

```
 if (input >= F_RangeLow &&  input <= F_RangeHigh )
```

---

now another thing you have to do is to initiate the counter with 0. that's because you want to stat counting from 0...

```
float F_Counter=0;
```

---

there is no need for 2 "{" at the start of the `main`
this is quite enough:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
.
.
.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your counter variables are uninitialized. So, they hold unknown values. So you have to change `float input, F_Counter, D_Counter, C_Counter, B_Counter, A_Counter;` to `float input, F_Counter=0, D_Counter=0, C_Counter=0, B_Counter=0, A_Counter=0;`

Comment: I did that. The problem is still the same. The counter will not update. Remains at 0

Comment: Are you saying that the range aspect of the macro will not work?

Answer (score 0):

```
float input, F_Counter, D_Counter, C_Counter, B_Counter, A_Counter;
```

In the `main()` context you are incrementing these values and none of them are initialized. You have undefined behavior when you have uninitialized vairables.

The values should be initialized like

```
float input =0,F_Counter=0;/* similarly for the rest */
```

Checking the range using the macros also needs to be fixed (0-49) doesn't mean you are checking the range from 0 to 49 . Comparison operators should be used in these cases.

Answer (score 0):

Your code has multiple major issues.

The first is that your `Range` macros don't expand to working code:

```
#define F_Range (0-49)
…
if (input == F_Range);
```

This expands to:

```
if (input == (0-49));
```

which is only true if `input` is `-49`. If you want to check if `input` is between 0 and 49, you'll have to do that explicitly:

```
if (input >= 0 && input <= 49)
```

Given your current level of understanding of C, it's probably best if you **don't use macros** for now. Leave them alone, write out code in full, and start using macros once you have a firm grasp of the language.

---

The following line:

```
printf("Total Number of grades 'A' (80-100) = %.2f",""A_Counter);
                                                    ^^
```

has a stray pair of quotation marks. (Does this even compile?)

---

Additionally:

- You've got a semicolon at the end of the `if` statement mentioned above, which makes it not work correctly.
- Your counter variables are not initialized to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Try Something Like This

```
#define F_Range(x) (x>=0 && x<=49)?true:false
#define D_Range(x) (x>=50 && x<=59)?true:false
#define C_Range(x) (x>=60 && x<=69)?true:false 
#define B_Range(x) (x>=70 && x<=79)?true:false 
#define A_Range(x) (x>=80 && x<=89)?true:false
```

AND

```
        scanf("%f",&input); //Get input from user
        if (F_Range(input));
        {
            F_Counter++;
        }
        else if (D_Range(input))
        {
            D_Counter++;
        }
        else if (C_Range(input))
        {
            C_Counter++;
        }
        else if (B_Range(input))
        {
            B_Counter++;
        }
        else if (A_Range(input))
        {
            A_Counter++;
        }
```

Comment: Why the redundant `? true : false`? That's making the macros only more complcated than they need to be.

Comment: and keep in mind with this kind of macros, that the one parameter to the macro is evaluated twice inside the expanded code, so no sideeffects with passing 'x' like 'F_Range(x++)' is possible

Comment: `if (F_Range(input));` remove `;`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

#define S_(x) #x
#define S(x) S_(x)
#define RANGE_S(x) S((x##_Range))
#define COUNTER(x) x##_Counter
#define DISP(x) \
printf("Total Number of grades '%c' %s = %d\n",\
    CHAR(x), RANGE_S(x), COUNTER(x))
#define CHECK(var, x) atoi(S(x##_Range)) <= var
#define CHAR(x) *#x

#define F_Range  0-49
#define D_Range 50-59
#define C_Range 60-69
#define B_Range 70-79
#define A_Range 80-100

void display(void);

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    float input;
    int COUNTER(A)=0, COUNTER(B)=0, COUNTER(C)=0, COUNTER(D)=0, COUNTER(F)=0;

    while(scanf("%f", &input)==1 && input != 999.f){
        if (CHECK(input, A)){
            ++COUNTER(A);
        } else if(CHECK(input, B)){
            ++COUNTER(B);
        } else if(CHECK(input, C)){
            ++COUNTER(C);
        } else if(CHECK(input, D)){
            ++COUNTER(D);
        } else if(CHECK(input, F)){
            ++COUNTER(F);
        }
    }
    DISP(A);
    DISP(B);
    DISP(C);
    DISP(D);
    DISP(F);
    return 0;
}
```